# Given a list of integers, how do I find the smallest integer that doesn't divide any one of them

Tags: algorithm, numbers

Given a list of integers , for example : 2, 3, 4, 6, 10, 20, 24. I have to find the smallest integer that doesn't divide any one of the given integers. In the example the answer is 7. There can be 10^6 integers and each can be less or equal 10^7 .
I tried this :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define siz 1000000
#define lim 10000000
int nmbrs[siz+1];
bool divflag[lim+1];
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int big=-1;
    for(int k=0; k<n; k++){
        scanf("%d",&nmbrs[k]);
        big = (nmbrs[k] > big )? nmbrs[k] : big;
    }
//    cout<<big;
    for(int k=0;k<n; k++){
        int tmp = nmbrs[k];
        divflag[tmp]=true;
        int root = sqrt(tmp);
        for(int j=2; j<=root; j++){
            int a = tmp/j;
            if(a*j == tmp){
                divflag[a] = divflag[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int k=2; k<=big+1; k++){
        if(divflag[k]==false){
            printf("%d\n",k); break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the time limit on the online judge is 1 second and I need a faster solution.

Comment: `for (i from 1 to maxElementIn(array)) { from index j which is greater than i in array} try dividing number and see if its divisible`

Comment: what do you mean by "from index j which is greater than i in array" ?

Comment: "I need an algorithm to do this, because [...]"? *Because*?? So what do you need if those things aren't true? A horse? A paintbrush?

Comment: Do you need an algorithm from scratch, or did you get stuck when trying to design one?

Comment: Need one from scratch @Cristik

Comment: I don't think this question to deserve down-votes in itself, but being asked twice "simultaneously": if the OP, a down-voter or anybody passing knows this to be an ongoing contest: please mark it as such (and provide a link). Thinking about max and square root. Examples where the answer isn't 7: 3, 10 or 3, 4, 10.

Answer (score 1):

- **SOLUTION 1 : brute force**

try every candidate from 2 to max(elements +1)

for every elements

test if candidate divides element, test with next element

you find the candidate, or try next

**least is around 90 000**

With 1 000 000 numbers between 1 and 10 000 000 => it takes around 130 sec (on my machine)

- **SOLUTION 2: smarter and faster**

For each element:

get the decomposition in factors and powers

then get every dividor

use a grid to flag every dividor

at last, find the least no-dividor in the grid

least is the same of course

=> it takes 16 sec

and there are a lot of (little) possible optimizations

- **SOLUTION 2BIS: more smarter and faster**

For each element, **in descendent order**

**check if already in the grid (see below): if yes, loop**

get the decomposition in factors and powers

then get every dividor

use a grid to flag every dividor

at last, find the least no-dividor in the grid

least is the same of course

=> it takes 13 sec - the more elements, the more fast it works

300 000 elements : 48 sec => 35 sec

Comment: How can you get every divider from factors and powers? It is not an easy task.

Comment: suppose you have N=a^2*b^4*c^3  then you have to iterate and get a^(0-1-2)*b^(0-1-2-3-4)*c^(0-1-2-3) . It is rather similar to get combinations.